# Is there an algorithm that, given a point cloud, infers an optimal wireframe (surface) structure?

Tags: ds.algorithms, cg.comp-geom

I have a point cloud that I would like to convert to a surface, in the form of a wireframe lattice structure.

This means, from a sequence of 3D points *(x,y,z)*, obtaining three 2D matrices *X,Y,Z* of the same size. In this way the points should be topologically related with a neighborhood of 4 (North, South, East, West). Such an organization of the points might, then, be plotted with functions such as *matplotlib*'s [`Axes3D.plot_wireframe`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots) or [`Axes3D.plot_surface`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_surface)

From what I understood, the relationship of a point with the neighboring points is characterized by having minimal distance. I think that this is a combinatorial optimization problem, and NP-hard.

Now the question: are there algorithms that, given a list of 3D points, return the three aforementioned matrices X,Y,Z ?

Thank you very much. I also hope this is the correct stack exchange forum for this kind of question.

Comment: What compatibility conditions do you impose on the directions? $\;$

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure I understood your question... you mean optimization constraints?

Comment: Can you explain/more precisely define a "wireframe lattice structure"?

Comment: What I mean with 'wireframe lattice structure' is just a grid, folded into a specific shape, for example, as representing the surface of an object. The nodes of this grid may well be the original points, with neighbourhood information attached.

Comment: Does this "neighbourhood information" include specifying which of its four neighbors is, eg., its eastern neighbor? $\;$

Comment: there is some theoretical/ algorithmic/ research angle here but this sounds more like an applied/ standardized raytracing type question to me where surfaces are "triangulated" for visualization purposes, and various well-known algorithms are built into GPU cards etc. the closest related se for it might be [gamedev.se]